# Meteor/React: How to integrate react component in main template

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, meteor

This is how my search page looks like in my meteor application:

**/client/main.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="circular search link icon"></i>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm completely new to react and I would like to use react for this simple search.

**/imports/ui/search.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Search extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ui icon input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <i class="circular search link icon"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But how do I have to use it for react properly? How do I use that component in the main template? And how can I set this input field centered on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better check the document and example first.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/155c0v2j/) is an example to answer your question.

Html just contains the empty `container` element.

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

The `App` component is the main component. You could use something like `Router`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Search` component as you made. In above, you could see `Search` component is used such that way in React.

About style, you can pass style object to component directly or make a css file.

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="ui icon input" style={searchContainerStyle}>
        <input type="text" style={searchInputStyle} placeholder="Search..." />
        <i class="circular search link icon"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const searchContainerStyle = {
  width: '50%',
  margin: '0 auto'
}

const searchInputStyle = {
  width: '100%'
}
```

Finally, render `App` under `container` element.

```
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```